# Android not resizing?

Tags: android, layout, scaling

I am developing my app on a 4in emulator in Eclipse. My phone is a 4.6in android device and when I test it on there, the content doesn't scale correctly.

It looks like the phone keeps the content at the same size, and it just moves everything up and leaves the extra space empty.

From what I have read, I thought it was supposed to keep the same layout as long as I use dp and not in. Does that mean my images need to be dp as well?

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is some code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tfltestbg2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tfl_header_port" 
            android:gravity = "center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:gravity = "center"
>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTakePic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity = "left"
            android:background="@drawable/takepic_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mMegaGalleryButton"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity = "center"
            android:background="@drawable/add_fotos" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mGalleryButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity = "right"
            android:background="@drawable/selectpic" 
            android:paddingLeft = "10dp"
            android:paddingRight = "10dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/outline_box"
        android:gravity="center">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
            android:gravity = "center"
            android:layout_gravity = "center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background = "@drawable/blank"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picsImage"
                android:layout_width = "100dp"
                android:layout_height = "100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background = "@drawable/picture_box"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mEditButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_pic_button" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUploadPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/upload_pic_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is really long, but I will go ahead and post it.

Comment: don't use background for imageviews, use src. your 3 first buttons have dp-fixed with, meaning they won't take all space available. use weight for this. all your first-level items have dp-fixed heigh, meaning they won't take up all available height. use weights.

Comment: okay, I have tried to stay away from weights because I didn't know what they did, so I will look up some tutorials on them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative layout instead of linear layout and dont use hardcoded dimesions like 40dp,50dp if use app for different sizes of screen.

[Relative layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your layout is that you used fixed values in wrong places! Instead `android:layout_width="100dp"` in button (this in horizontal layout) you should use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`.
You have to set none zero value for `layout_weight` for this buttons so they could share space with other siblings in this layout.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to convert fixed dp to weight:

change this:

android:layout_width="100dp"

to this:

android:layout_width="0dp"

android:layout_weight="100"

do it for all buttons and they will look exactly like they was in 4" and will scale perfect in any screen.